# LC3 Machine language

Tags: assembly, machine-code

in LC-3 machine language how can a number of 16 bits left shifted by n bits? like if we have
15  14  13  12  11  10  9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2  1   0
and the binary numbers are 
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

then how can we left shift 3?

Answer (score 3):

Because LC-3 apparently has no shift operations you have to do it yourself.

some folks dicussing an LC-3 simulator and bit shift operations here http://www.asmcommunity.net/board/index.php?topic=28978.0 indicate that:

> for each bit position of shift to the left, its multiply by 2 (or add it to itself if you like)

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you very much. and i hope your identified post will help me :)